# Android studio 2.3 Navigation drawer: app quit when fragment is selected

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm starting to create my first android app.

I've read tons of articles and posts on this topic, but they were quite old and I can't find any help in there because I think that it's somehow different now.

Everything seems to be just as in the tutorials I followed, but when I click on a drawer, the app quit.

There is my content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="be.boisdelacambre.ecole.ecolebdc.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've created a new blank fragment (all boxes checked) called AccueilFragment. I've added a few text labels in fragment_accueil.xml.

When I click on the first drawer, it crashes:

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_accueil) {
            AccueilFragment accueilFragment = new AccueilFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, accueilFragment, "Accueil").commit();
```

... (the file continue as default)

Could someone tell me why it goes wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: AccueilFragment  is  support v4 fragment?

Comment: I found an error: ava.lang.RuntimeException: be.boisdelacambre.ecole.ecolebdc.MainActivity@e665e84 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener                                                                                   atbe.boisdelacambre.ecole.ecolebdc.AccueilFragment.onAttach(AccueilFragment.java:83)

Comment: post fragment code..

Comment: In the public void onAttach(Context context) {, I've a "+ " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener" there wasn't any mention of that in the tutorial I followed

Comment: public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

Comment: remove that method and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found my answer:

I had clicked the 2 boxes when creating the fragment.

I had those function:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
```

that I changed for:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
```

And it work now. Thanks to all !